# Unable to withdraw information from MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList variable in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to withdraw information from inside a MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList variable in VBA. However, every time I try to reference the information in the item, I get an error: "object variable or with block variable not set". See image below. "xNodes" has been created with information from parsing an XML. You can see there are two "Items". I am able to withdraw information from Item 1, but I  get the error every time I try to take information from item 2. It is important to note that everything useful from this XML is going to be in Item 2 for different nodes. See code below. The section labeled "DEBUG" is where I was experimenting with different ways to get the info. I am unable to extract and set to a variable. Any help is appreciated - thanks!

[image]

```
' Define the variables needed to create our XML Document
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode


' Create the document
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    'Load the response into the document
    xDoc.LoadXML (strResponse)



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' DEBUG
Dim rsNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim rsObj As IXMLDOMNode
Dim rsStr As Variant

Set xNodes = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("series_id")
'rsObj = xNodes.Item(2).Text ' <-- ERROR HERE: I want to somehow get that text from item 2. I have tried everything.
'With xNodes
'    rsObj = xNodes.Item(2)
'End With




''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Dom index starts at 0 so the first item is at index 0, the second at index 1. Try `.Item(1)` if you want to access the second item in the selection.

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver.